# Getting rid of \r\n text showing up in web scraper

Tags: javascript, newline

I am using async to fetch table tags in a website. It works great, however it is putting all of the \r\n tags at the bottom of my table. I can't figure out how to get rid of them in my .match(). Anyone have any answers?

````
            var fetchCommand = "https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=" + encodeURIComponent("sampleurl");
            (async () => {
                const response = await fetch(fetchCommand);
                const text = await response.text();
                let result = text.match(/(?<=\<table>).*(?=\<\/table>)/);       
                console.log(result);
                let html_content = document.getElementById("table");
                html_content.innerHTML = result;
                return html_content;
            })()
</script>```
````

Comment: The “match” function is not for replacing, try using “replace” or “replaceAll” (replaceAll requires “/g” at the end and “/“ at the start). “ ‘Hello 1 1 World’.replaceAll(/1/g,”2”)” outputs to “Hello 2 2 World”

Answer (score 0):

Works for me by parsing the response `JSON` with `DOMParser()` and then use `querySelector()` to get the table. You might want to look for all tables with `querySelectorAll()`. I also use `outerHTML` on the table element to add it to the DOM because innerHTML strips the html tags.

```js
function fetchTable() {
  fetch(`https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=${encodeURIComponent('https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp')}`)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data.contents, 'text/html');
      const firstTable = htmlDoc.querySelector('table');

      html_content.innerHTML = firstTable.outerHTML;
    })
}
```

Edit: Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/q0dj7rvz/

If you keep having issues with the end of line characters, please post the URL with the table.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: @TylerShields You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark my answer as "solved".